# Combined Probability

Tags: probability, fractions

$$P(A)\frac{2}{3}, P(A | B)= \frac{1}{3}$$ and $$P(A ∪ B)= \frac{4}{5}.$$ Find  P(B).

I honestly have no idea how to even approach this problem, as I cannot find any helpful online notes on Combined probability. For instance, I don't even know how to find P(A ⋂ B) if given P(A ∪ B), P(A) and P(B).

So how would I solve a simple problem like finding P(A ⋂ B), and then how would I use this knowledge to solve the question mentioned above?

Comment: $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B) -P(A\cap B)$.  Also $P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)\times P(B)$.  See the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)

Comment: I don't know what a "combined probability" would be. It seems to me there are various ways of combining knowledge about probabilities of different events. Try using more specific terms when you describe things. $P(A\cup B)$ is the probability of a _union_ of two events; if you Google "probability of union" you get plenty of useful information.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to find $P(A \cap B)$, but you can use the knowledge that $P(A \cap B) = P(A|B) \times P(B)$

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_exclusion_principle):

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

$\frac{4}{5} = \frac{2}{3} + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

But $P(A \cap B) = P(A|B) \times P(B)$

So $\frac{4}{5} - \frac{2}{3} = P(B) - P(A|B) \times P(B)$

We know $P(A | B)$

$\frac{2}{15} = P(B) (1 - \frac{1}{3})$

$P(B) = \frac{1}{5}$